# Is there a phrase for doing a particular thing only to have a formal right to deny somebody something?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I know that the title is rather unclear; basically, let me describe the situation this way:

> You have been assigned by your teacher to choose students for a school project many would like to take part in, for some reason or another. You've chosen a bunch of people you not only consider appropriate for this project - they are also your friends. And then, a few people you don't like tell you they would like to participate. Instead of telling them just 'go away, I don't like you, you're not going to be in this project' you inform them that in order to take part in this project, they have to do a particular assignment, e.g. describing an approach to a problem the project covers - 'this assignment tests whether you're appropriate for this project'. And here's the trick: **you know they won't do it** - either because the assignment is purposely difficult, or they won't have the time, or *anything* like that. And now **you have formal right to deny them participation in the project** - 'because you failed to hand in the assignment'.

Is there a nice phrase for doing so?

Comment: In college we had "weed out classes" for freshmen to do just that. But formally they were *prerequisites* for any higher level class.

Comment: Well, I don't think the term "weed out classes" is best here, as it does not highlight the *moral* aspect - doing something rather immoral to have a formal right

Comment: Setting up barriers.

Comment: You could also be "setting them up to fail".